# Render a partial as a radio button is checked, using ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

[My search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyt2K.png)

These are my radio buttons

```
    <% [ 'categorie', 'strutture', 'attivita', 'servizi' ].each do |type| %>
      <%= radio_button_tag 'search_type', type, params[:search_type] == type %>
      <%= type.humanize %>
    <% end %>
```

i would like to render a partial as soon as one of them is selected.

I think this should be very similar to the ajax call i'm using for the instant search, that is:

this code in application.js

```
$("#facilities_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#facilities_search").attr("action"), $("#facilities_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
```

and this in index.js.erb

```
$("#facilities").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("facilities")) %>");
```

Please can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was quite easy!

The point was to add this to my application.js

```
  $("#search_type_categorie, #search_type_attivita, #search_type_servizi, #search_type_strutture").live("change", function() {
    $.get($("#global_search").attr("action"), $("#global_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
```